# (PDO Lib) How to fetch row by row | FaaPz / PDO

Tags: php

I'm trying to select the 10 most higher 'coins' value in a database and extract them as string for each row ('id' and 'coins'). I'm stuck because the only examples are not completed for everyone. Here the link to the documentation -> [FaaPz/PDO](https://github.com/FaaPz/PDO/blob/2.x/docs/Statement/Select.md)

So i try to make this but i'm too "weak" in PHP to really complete it

(The SQL code i try to do):
**SELECT * FROM `leaderboard` ORDER BY `coins` DESC LIMIT 10**

```
$database->select()
    ->from('leaderboard')
    ->orderBy('coins', 'DESC')
    ->limit(10) // ERROR here ?? (Argument #1 ($limit) must be of type FaaPz\PDO\Clause\LimitInterface, int given)
    ->execute(); // How i fetch the result of each row selected ??
```

Comment: That's not PDO. I think it's Doctrine.

Comment: If it's Doctrine, you should use `->setMaxResults(10)`.

Comment: Barmar the pdo is an extention with composer called "ext_pdo"

Comment: I know what PDO is. It's being used internally by Doctrine QueryBuilder to execute the query.

Comment: Ah, now I see you linked to the documentation of the library you're using, which calls PDO.

Comment: Oh, that's even worse. This guy has named his library PDO, even though it's not the *real* PDO.

Comment: As i told in my post i'm pettry weak in php and i try to learn more. i don"t really understand what you are meaning by Doctrine

Comment: There's a standard extension called PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. That composer library uses the same name, but it's completely different.

Comment: Oh, and what is the differance?

Comment: They're completely different. The built-in PDO is just a way to execute SQL queries, you have to write the SQL yourself. `FaaPz/PDO` is a query builder that uses a high-level abstraction and writes the SQL for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $out = $database->select()
    ->from('leaderboard')
    ->orderBy('coins', 'DESC')
    ->limit(new Limit(10)) 
    ->execute(); 
print_r( $out->fetchAll());
```

check it out and tell me if that was the case

Comment: It's documented [here](https://github.com/FaaPz/PDO/blob/2.x/docs/Clause/Limit.md)

Comment: Class "Limit" not found in

Comment: use FaaPz\PDO\Clause\Limit;

Comment: Work fine now thanks, i won't give you the correct answer since it's answering a part of the question

Comment: i edit code - try now

Comment: giving -1 without writing a comment should be punishable